# Dual boot windows 8 from a 12.04 install?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I've got a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to dual boot Windows 8 with it.

Is this possible? All tutorials I can find are for the other way around.

Comment: I'm reluctant to say this is a dupe because this question talk about Win7, but it should be similar enough to help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu. If possible, installing Windows first is much simpler.

Comment: They have different bootloaders, so it must be a bit different.

Comment: Well I think you want to use Grub2 as your bootloader anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials around, and indeed, most say you need to install Windows first. However, Windows 8 also has a bootloader that you can use. The problem is often that Windows doesn't recognize the Linux partition and ignores it in the bootloader, kicking you straight into Windows.
Look here to see how to add Linux to the bootloader: https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager